# I'm trying to make a program to show the dolar value, but I can't make it print it to me the information I want

Tags: python, python-requests

So, here's the script. I'm using this api i found on the internet and it works, but when I tried to make it print only the info I want the following error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/perei/OneDrive/Documentos/Evylla/python/projetos python/cotacao_dolar.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("Moeda estrangeira: {}".format(dolar_cot["code"]))
KeyError: 'code'
```

```
import requests
import json

dolar = requests.get("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/all/USD-BRL")
dolar_cot = dolar.json()

# print(dolar.text)

if "status" == 404:
    print("Moeda não encontrada")
else:
    print("")
    print("Moeda estrangeira: {}".format(dolar_cot["code"]))
    print("Moeda nacional: {}".format(dolar_cot["codein"]))
    print("Moeda estrangeira: {}".format(dolar_cot["code"]))
    print("Momento mais baixo: {}".format(dolar_cot["low"]))
    print("Moeda mais alto: {}".format(dolar_cot["high"]))
    print("Oferta: {}".format(dolar_cot["bid"]))
    print("Pedido: {}".format(dolar_cot["ask"]))
```

Comment: What does the json look like?

Comment: You are very close, however upon closer inspection you may notice that the API returns the key "USD" and then the values.
You may want to add on to the .json() call to make it: `dolar_cot = dolar.json()["USD"]`

Comment: This worked out perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the response when you send a get request to the API

```
{"USD":{
  "code":"USD",
  "codein":"BRL","name":"Dólar Comercial",  
  "high":"5.327",
  "low":"5.2477",
  "varBid":"0.0104",
  "pctChange":"0.2",
  "bid":"5.3003",
  "ask":"5.3033",
  "timestamp":"1599253196",
  "create_date":"2020-09-04 21:00:01"}
}
```

As you can see all the fields are nested within `"USD"`.
So just change `dolar_cot = dolar.json()` to `dolar_cot = dolar.json()["USD"]`

Comment: Actually, just changing `dolar_cot = dolar.json()` to `dolar_cot = dolar.json()["USD"]` will do it, and you won't need to edit all the print calls.

Comment: Also, `print` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: Ahh, much better! Updated my answer